# How can I optimize my code with angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I made a lot of research, but I did not find an answer or I didn't understand the code someone wrote - it is not working. Now I have a lot of code. I'd like to optimize my code with AngularJS - e.g. `ng-repeat` or something like that.   Example are the if lines.. and there are 4 more...

```
$scope.url = "an URL";
$http.get($scope.url)
.then(function(response) {
    $scope.x = response.data;
    var y1 = response.data.a.tools;
    var y2 = response.data.b.tools;
    var y3 = response.data.c.tools;
    var y4 = response.data.d.tools;
    var y5 = response.data.e.tools;
    var y6 = response.data.f.tools;

    //...

    var boxArray = ["jenkins", "gitHub", "jira", "urbanCode"];

    if (y1[0] == boxArray[0]) {$scope.jenkins1 = boxArray[0];} else {$scope.jenkins1 ="";};
    if (y1[1] == boxArray[1]) {$scope.gitHub1 = boxArray[1];} else {$scope.gitHub1 ="";};
    if (y1[2] == boxArray[2]) {$scope.jira1 = boxArray[2];} else {$scope.jira1 ="";};
    if (y1[3] == boxArray[3]) {$scope.urbanCode1 = boxArray[3];} else {$scope.urbanCode1 ="";};

    if (y2[0] == boxArray[0]) {$scope.jenkins2 = boxArray[0];} else {$scope.jenkins2 ="";};
    if (y2[1] == boxArray[1]) {$scope.gitHub2 = boxArray[1];} else {$scope.gitHub2 ="";};
    if (y2[2] == boxArray[2]) {$scope.jira2 = boxArray[2];} else {$scope.jira2 ="";};
    if (y2[3] == boxArray[3]) {$scope.urbanCode2 = boxArray[3];} else {$scope.urbanCode2 ="";};

    //.....
```

I'd like to get the names back from `boxArray` for my Checkboxes and not true or false.

Comment: please post some json data you are getting from http call and format your code

Comment: Asking "how to optimize" may be too broad. Can you narrow it down to something more specific?

Comment: yes and sorry that the question was to broad. I just started, thats why I don´t know which specific code is important for you . Next time I will give you the more details. The answer from georgeawg was helpful, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The list of `y` vars can be converted to an array:

```
 var abc = "abcdef";
 var yList = [];
 for (var i=0; i<abc.length; i++) {
    yList[i] = response.data[abc[i]].tools;
 };
```

The above example uses a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) to interate the names, `data.a`, `data.b`...

Then the template can use `ng-repeat`:

```
 <tr ng-repeat= "y in yList">
     {{y}}
 </tr>
```

A similar technique can be used to convert the data in each row to an array. The template can then use a nested `ng-repeat`.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="y in yList">
     <td ng-repeat="box in boxArray">
          {{y[box]}}
     </td>
 </tr>
```